# Understanding how to use tf.dataset.map()

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I am converting some code which originally used JPEGs as the input to use Matlab MAT files.  The code contains the lines:

```
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(PATH + 'train/*.mat')
train_dataset = train_dataset.shuffle(BUFFER_SIZE) 
train_dataset = train_dataset.map(load_image_train)
```

If I loop through the dataset and print() each element before map(), I get a set of tensors with the file paths visible.

However, within the load_image_train function, this is not the case, the output of print() is:

`Tensor("add:0", shape=(), dtype=string)`

I would like to use the scipy.io.loadmat() function to get the data from my mat files but it fails because the path is a tensor and not a string.  What does dataset.map() do that appears to make the literal string value no longer visible?  How do I extract the string so I can use it as input for scipy.io.loadmat()?

Apologies if this is a stupid question, relatively new to Tensorflow and still trying to understand.  A lot of discussion I can find of related issues only applies to TF v1.  Thank you for any help!

Comment: The function for `dataset.map` works like a graph mode. You should use `tf.numpy_function` to call python functions, or convert them into a different format.  TFIO does not have .mat file support yet: https://github.com/tensorflow/io/issues/270

Comment: Hi @asher1213, Can you give a minimum reproducible code for the error? and an example .MAT files you are trying to load as a dataset?

Answer (score 7):

In the below code, I am using `tf.data.Dataset.list_files` to read a file_path of a image. In the `map` function I am loading the image and doing the `crop_central`(basically crops the center part of the image for the given percentage, here I have specified the percentage by `np.random.uniform(0.50, 1.00)`).

As you rightly mentioned, it is difficult to read the file as the the file path is of `tf.string` type and the `load_img` or any other function to read the image file would require simple `string` type.

So here is how you can do it -

1. You need to decorate your map function with `tf.py_function(load_file_and_process, [x], [tf.float32]).` You can find more about it [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/py_function).
2. You can retrieve the `string` from the `tf.string` using `bytes.decode(path.numpy()`.

Below is the complete code for you reference. You can replace it with your image path while you run this code.

```
%tensorflow_version 2.x
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.preprocessing.image import load_img
from keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array, array_to_img
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def load_file_and_process(path):
    image = load_img(bytes.decode(path.numpy()), target_size=(224, 224))
    image = img_to_array(image)
    image = tf.image.central_crop(image, np.random.uniform(0.50, 1.00))
    return image

train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.list_files('/content/bird.jpg')
train_dataset = train_dataset.map(lambda x: tf.py_function(load_file_and_process, [x], [tf.float32]))

for f in train_dataset:
  for l in f:
    image = np.array(array_to_img(l))
    plt.imshow(image)
```

Output -

[image]

Hope this answers your question. Happy Learning.

Comment: @asher1213 - Can you please upvote and accept the answer if it answers your question. Thank You.

Comment: Better than those answers suggesting `from_generator`, though both disable conversion to a graph.